# Problems with @ViewChild

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, viewchild

I am currently creating a @viewChild component, tabs in my app. However, upon inserting the following lines:

```
@ViewChild('tabs') tabs: IonTabs;
```

I am facing an error **'Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.'**

Please helps. Thks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the error.

Insert the new line below:

```
@ViewChild('tabs', {static: true}) tabs: IonTabs;
```

Hopes this helps anyone !

Comment: Note that the `static` parameter is only required from Angular 8.0 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the `static` property in Metadata Properties (From Angular 8 onwards).

```
@ViewChild('tabs', {static: false}) tabs: IonTabs;
```

`static` property should be set `true` to resolve query results before change detection runs and `false` for depending on binding resolution (Structural directives `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`,...) for query resolution.

`{static: false}` will be used in most cases ensuring that query will be resolved after change detection runs.

The `{static: false}` is going to be the default fallback in Angular 9.

You can read more here:
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description